# SWF file - insert an image

Tags: flash

I have a swf file given to me. It is basically a horizontal scrolling ticker of images. How do I insert images in the ticker? I have looked online and see Flash Decompiler (did not work). Downloaded swf editor and I can see images but it does not allow me to add an image. This is for some website who was built by people who are not there and we don't have code but only Flash file (swf)

Comment: Since it's for a website, why not just create a new one using HTML5 code? If you need the other existing images then just extract from SWF (has jpg png files embeded?)... If you simply embed more new images how can you guarantee the SWF's code will know what to do with these? Will it know they even exist? So now you'll have to write more AS3 code... It becomes easier to just recreate than to edit a de-compiled product. Wether you know Flash or HTML5 an image ticker is a one-day mission (check web tutorials for such a thing).

Comment: The only problem is - I don't want to change the existing behavior of flash. They are doing few other things apart from ticker. I thought the easiest way is to just insert the desired image in ticker and then wrap swf back. I was able to decompile the file and see images with a Flash decompiler but it does not allow me to insert images.